# Word for not close friendship

Tags: word-choice, word-request

According to the Oxford dictionary:

> Friend - a person who you know well and who you like a lot, but who is
> usually not a member of your family.

What noun you can use for a person whos you know not enough to name a friend, but occasionally friendly speak with him/her?

Update based on comment:

> I have many friends and three close friends

Or

> I have many (?) and three friends

Comment: An acquaintance, I'd say.

Comment: Note that the English *friend* is a somewhat broader and less commital term than the seemingly equivalent ones in other languages. In Polish I'd distinguish between a *kolega* / *znajomy* (someone I might occasionally go out for a beer with or chat, but usually in a larger group) and *przyjaciel* (someone I have a deep personal relationship with), but in English I'd probably use *friend* for both, maybe describing the latter as a *close friend*.

Comment: @MaciejStachowski, I know the Polish language, better than English, the word that I searching for is "znajomy". As I understood it can be translated as "friend" ("I have many friends and three close friends").

Comment: @BogdanSamchuk Polish *znajomy* can be translated as either *friend* or *acquaintance*, depending on how well you know the person. *Acquaintance* would be the guy at work you say hi to and sometimes have a smoke or a chat with, *friend* would be the one you might call on a Friday evening to hit the town. Basically if on a scale of 1 to 10 the line between *znajomy* / *przyjaciel* is at around 8, the one between *acquaintance* and *friend* is closer to 3 or so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to dictionary.com

> Acquaintance(noun)- a person known to one, but usually not a close friend.